# Wordpress: Image and product gallery combined not working as expected

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress

Please help me to write a working code for the WordPress plugin in the form of banner and product images. when I click next button it will change both images and new products, I hope you can help me.

I tried to write my code but it is not working. Here is the code I wrote:

```
<?php 
if($settings['list_tab']){
    do_action( 'before' );
    if ( $list -> have_posts() ){ ?>
        <div id="product-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="bwp-slider <?php echo esc_attr($layout); ?>">       
            <?php if($title1) { ?>
                <div class="block">
                    <?php if($description) { ?>
                        <div class="page-description"><?php echo esc_html($description); ?></div>
                    <?php } ?> 
                    <div class="title-block"><h2><?php echo esc_html($title1); ?></h2></div>   
                </div> 
            <?php } ?>
            <?php foreach ($settings['list_tab'] as  $item){ ?>
                <div class="content-product-list">  
                    <div class="slider products-list grid slick-carousel" data-dots="<?php echo esc_attr($show_pag);?>" data-slidesToScroll="true" data-nav="<?php echo esc_attr($show_nav);?>" data-columns4="<?php echo $columns4; ?>" data-columns3="<?php echo $columns3; ?>" data-columns2="<?php echo $columns2; ?>" data-columns1="<?php echo $columns1; ?>" data-columns="<?php echo $columns; ?>"> 
                    <?php while($list->have_posts()): $list->the_post();?>
                        <?php
                        global $product, $post, $wpdb, $average;    
                        $orginal_price = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_regular_price', true );    
                        $sale_price = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_sale_price', true );  
                        $symboy = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( get_woocommerce_currency() );
                        $product_hot_label = isset($bedesk_settings['product-hot-label']) && !empty($bedesk_settings['product-hot-label']) ? $bedesk_settings['product-hot-label'] : esc_html__('Hot','wpbingo');
                        $product_sale_label = bedesk_get_product_discount();
                        $product_sale = bedesk_get_config('product-sale',true);
                        add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bedesk_woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 15 );
                        ?>
                        <div class="item-product">  
                            <div class="item-product-content products-entry clearfix product-wapper">
                                <div class="content-image">
                                    <div class="products-thumb">
                                        <a  href="<?php esc_url(the_permalink()); ?>">
                                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                                            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $product->get_id(), 'shop_single'); ?>
                                            <?php }else{ ?>
                                                <img src="<?php echo esc_attr(get_template_directory_uri().'/images/placeholder.jpg') ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr__('No thumb', 'wpbingo') ?>">
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </a>
                                        <?php if($product_sale ) : ?>
                                            <div class='product-lable'>
                                                <?php if(isset($bedesk_settings['product-hot']) && $bedesk_settings['product-hot']) : ?>
                                                    <?php if ($product->is_featured()) : ?>
                                                        <?php echo apply_filters('woocommerce_featured_flash', '<div class="vgwc-label vgwc-featured hot">' . esc_html($product_hot_label) . '</div>', $post, $product); ?>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?> 
                                                <?php if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) : ?>
                                                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', '<span class="onsale">' . esc_html($product_sale_label) . '</span>', $post, $product ); ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <div class='product-button'>
                                            <?php do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item'); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="products-content">
                                    <?php woocommerce_template_loop_rating(); ?>
                                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>
                                    <h3 class="product-title"><a href="<?php esc_url(the_permalink()); ?>"><?php esc_html(the_title()); ?></a></h3>
                                    <div class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></div>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}?>
```

Please help me to rectify my code to match this image I am giving:
[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8yip.jpg)

Comment: Someone has added your code for you. Could you add a description of what isn't working.